# SQL Server: Copying data from a table to another without using a cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hello I have to migrate data from one table to another and I wanna avoid using a cursor.

Using a cursor this would be very easy, since I'd have to do something like this:

```
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
select Id, dataToMigrate
from OriginTable
where bar <> 'foo'

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor into @Id, @DataToMigrate

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE DestinationTable
    SET Value = @DataToMigrate
    Where Id = @Id

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor into @Id, @DataToMigrate
END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

However, this feels wrong. I'm sure there must be an easier and more clever way of doing this without a cursor.

Anyone knows a better way?

Comment: Using sub-selects wont help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes a cursor is completely the wrong way to do this. Kudos for looking for a better way. You can do this with a simple update statement.

```
update d
set Value = o.DataToMigrate
from DestinationTable d
join OriginTable o on o.SomeColumn = d.SomeColumn
where o.bar <> 'foo'
```

Comment: where clause requried

Comment: Oops forgot that little bit. ;)

Comment: So this basically works like doing a select and then copying data from one column of the resulting dataset into the other?

Answer (score 4):

A set based solution is the best choice in your case. You can use an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` for this. You do need to know that this is merely updating your rows, it isn't inserting any data.

```
UPDATE D
SET D.Value = O.dataToMigrate
FROM DestinationTable D
INNER JOIN OriginTable O
    ON D.Id = O.Id
WHERE O.bar <> 'foo'
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with an UPDATE statement, as far as I can tell.

This is from memory, but it'd look like this:

```
UPDATE dt
SET    Value = ot.dataToMigrate
FROM   DestinationTable dt
   JOIN OriginTable ot
       ON dt.Id = ot.Id
WHERE bar <> 'foo'
```

The syntax has to be exactly right, but it's very possible to join two tables and update one from the other.